# Where can I find a list of constants for Request Transaction Types for Authorize.Net's API?

Tags: constants, authorize.net

I cannot find documentation on the list of constants for Request Transaction Types. In the examples I've come across, in a disorganized way, the two common types of "authOnly Transaction" and "authCaptureTransaction".

Where does Authorize.Net document this on their website with a full list and the meaning of each constant?

Are there only two?

Comment: They're all in their [documentation](http://www.authorize.net/content/dam/authorize/documents/AIM_guide.pdf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look into the the [API Schema](https://api.authorize.net/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd) of Authorize.Net these are the list of `transactionType` accepted by the API :

```
authOnlyTransaction
authCaptureTransaction
captureOnlyTransaction
refundTransaction
priorAuthCaptureTransaction
voidTransaction
getDetailsTransaction
authOnlyContinueTransaction
authCaptureContinueTransaction
```

Answer (score 1):

All of the constants and other related documentation can be found in the [AIM documentation](http://www.authorize.net/content/dam/authorize/documents/AIM_guide.pdf).